# "unexpected token" when using stringify

Tags: node.js, browserify

When using browserify with stringify transform, this error appears:

`Unexpected Token (1:0) while parsing file`

These were the browserify transforms being used in the package.json

```
...
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "envify",
    "babelify",
    "brfs",
    "stringify"
  ]
},
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably caused by conflicts with stringify and other transforms

In my case it was brfs, which was being loaded before stringify. Swapping the order fixed the problem

i.e.

broken:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "brfs",
    "stringify"
  ]
}
```

works:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "stringify",
    "brfs"
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That is invalid RFC 4627 JSON. Try this:

```
{
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "envify",
      "babelify",
      "brfs",
      "stringify"
    ]
  }
},
```